# Triggered click don't work propertly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have binded some links click event.

When I click one of them link is captured and default prevented but when I make my own logic and trigger click again, href or onclick attributes are not triggered.

Fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/oo80rmhd/15/

```js
allowPaymentSubmit = false;

$(document).on('click', '#links a', function(event) {

  $('#console').append('clicked<br>');
  var el = $(this);

  if (!allowPaymentSubmit) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //My Ajax call logic
    //On ajax success set to true and trigger click
    allowPaymentSubmit = true;
    el.trigger('click');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
  <a href="http://www.google.es">Href</a><br>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#paypal_payment_form').submit();">OnClick</a>
</div>

<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you triggering it again? why prevent default in the first place if you want the click to happen?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a link vs a button?

Comment: I only want to trigger his own href or onclick attribute if ajax is successfully.

Comment: Just submit the form... why reclick the link?

Comment: @epascarello read the code comments. Click in the ajax success only

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: I am saying, the only reason you are clicking the link is to call the form submit.... so just call the submit directly

Comment: @epascarello, he put the minimized code here. For sure, he needs this indirect submission. So, let's focus on the question. Not on the reason.

Comment: @Mojtaba And sometimes the simplest solution is the best one.